MyBatis - Issue while passing parameter object to the query
I have a Spring application with MyBatis.
Facing an issue while passing parameter object. It works fine if I hardcode the values in query. It doesn't return anything also no error when I pass the values in parameter object.
I am getting following debugs of query and parameter object:
where lab.BrandId = ? and lab.CategoryId = ? and lab.ModelId = ?

parameterObject : GetLabsRequest [showAll=null, brandId=1033, categoryId=1000, modelId=2310, labNumber=null]

My query in mapper:
<select id="getLabsModelId" resultMap="GetAllResult"        parameterType="com.lab.dealer.apps.GetLabsRequest">

      select distinct
        ..............
      where
    Lab.BrandId = #{brandId}
    and Lab.CategoryId = #{categoryId}
    and Lab.ModelId = #{modelId}        
</select>

Additionally, I am getting following debugs after turning on the debugs in apache.mybatis
[APP] 2024-10-23 00:50:45 DEBUG SqlSessionUtils:49 - SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@105743f] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
[APP] 2024-10-23 00:50:45 DEBUG SpringManagedTransaction:49 - JDBC Connection [795244813, URL=...............] will not be managed by Spring
[APP] 2024-10-23 00:50:45 DEBUG SqlSessionUtils:49 - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@105743f]

I want to know whether am I doing anything wrong and how to make sqlsession sync to active.
Thanks in advance

Debug log should be enabled against your mapper's fully-qualified name, not against apache.mybatis. If you share an executable demo project with minimum setup on GitHub, I would take a look. Here are some project templates and examples.
